# PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'admin_newapmasala.core_config_data' doesn't exist in

Tags: magento2.2

Following error occurs with my website address please help me out what to do:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'admin_newapmasala.core_config_data' doesn't exist in /usr/local/apache/htdocs/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228 Stack trace: #0 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(93): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array) #2 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement.php(303): Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql->_execute(Array) #3 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array) #4 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array) #5 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(533): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array) #6 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(596): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array) #7 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(737): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->query(Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Select), Array) #8 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection/Db/FetchStrategy/Query.php(21): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll(Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Select), Array) #9 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection/AbstractDb.php(774): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategy\Query->fetchAll(Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Select), Array) #10 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection/AbstractDb.php(670): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->_fetchAll(Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Select)) #11 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection/AbstractDb.php(574): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->getData() #12 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection/AbstractDb.php(559): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->loadWithFilter(false, false) #13 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection.php(831): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->load() #14 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Source/RuntimeConfigSource.php(83): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection->getIterator() #15 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Source/RuntimeConfigSource.php(63): Magento\Config\App\Config\Source\RuntimeConfigSource->loadConfig() #16 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config/ConfigSourceAggregated.php(40): Magento\Config\App\Config\Source\RuntimeConfigSource->get('') #17 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System/Reader.php(60): Magento\Framework\App\Config\ConfigSourceAggregated->get() #18 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/generated/code/Magento/Config/App/Config/Type/System/Reader/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System\Reader->read() #19 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php(292): Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System\Reader\Proxy->read() #20 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php(191): Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->readData() #21 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php(152): Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->loadDefaultScopeData('default') #22 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(131): Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->get('default/newreli...') #23 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(80): Magento\Framework\App\Config->get('system', 'default/newreli...') #24 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-new-relic-reporting/Model/Config.php(91): Magento\Framework\App\Config->getValue('newrelicreporti...') #25 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-new-relic-reporting/Plugin/HttpPlugin.php(49): Magento\NewRelicReporting\Model\Config->isNewRelicEnabled() #26 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(121): Magento\NewRelicReporting\Plugin\HttpPlugin->beforeCatchException(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap), Object(Zend_Db_Statement_Exception)) #27 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap), Object(Zend_Db_Statement_Exception)) #28 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->___callPlugins('catchException', Array, Array) #29 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(261): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->catchException(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap), Object(Zend_Db_Statement_Exception)) #30 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor)) #31 {main} Next Zend_Db_Statement_Exception: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'admin_newapmasala.core_config_data' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `core_config_data` AS `main_table` in /usr/local/apache/htdocs/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235 Stack trace: #0 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(93): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array) #1 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement.php(303): Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql->_execute(Array) #2 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array) #3 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array) #4 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(533): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array) #5 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(596): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array) #6 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(737): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->query(Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Select), Array) #7 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection/Db/FetchStrategy/Query.php(21): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll(Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Select), Array) #8 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection/AbstractDb.php(774): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategy\Query->fetchAll(Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Select), Array) #9 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection/AbstractDb.php(670): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->_fetchAll(Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Select)) #10 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection/AbstractDb.php(574): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->getData() #11 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection/AbstractDb.php(559): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->loadWithFilter(false, false) #12 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection.php(831): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->load() #13 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Source/RuntimeConfigSource.php(83): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection->getIterator() #14 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Source/RuntimeConfigSource.php(63): Magento\Config\App\Config\Source\RuntimeConfigSource->loadConfig() #15 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config/ConfigSourceAggregated.php(40): Magento\Config\App\Config\Source\RuntimeConfigSource->get('') #16 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System/Reader.php(60): Magento\Framework\App\Config\ConfigSourceAggregated->get() #17 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/generated/code/Magento/Config/App/Config/Type/System/Reader/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System\Reader->read() #18 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php(292): Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System\Reader\Proxy->read() #19 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php(191): Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->readData() #20 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php(152): Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->loadDefaultScopeData('default') #21 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(131): Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->get('default/newreli...') #22 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(80): Magento\Framework\App\Config->get('system', 'default/newreli...') #23 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-new-relic-reporting/Model/Config.php(91): Magento\Framework\App\Config->getValue('newrelicreporti...') #24 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-new-relic-reporting/Plugin/HttpPlugin.php(49): Magento\NewRelicReporting\Model\Config->isNewRelicEnabled() #25 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(121): Magento\NewRelicReporting\Plugin\HttpPlugin->beforeCatchException(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap), Object(Zend_Db_Statement_Exception)) #26 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap), Object(Zend_Db_Statement_Exception)) #27 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->___callPlugins('catchException', Array, Array) #28 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(261): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->catchException(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap), Object(Zend_Db_Statement_Exception)) #29 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor)) #30 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to check that database admin_newapmasala and table core_config_data inside that database exist. Check magento db configuration app/etc/env.php , amy be db configuration was changed by someone, or database was erased.
Thanks,
Pavel S.

Answer (score 0):

try and check weather you installed magento correctly and have ran all the commands
the following command worked for mr

```
php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

`php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento setup:di:compile`

`rm -rf pub/static/frontend/`

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

`php bin/magento cache:clean`

`chmod -R 777 pub/static/`

`chmod -R 777 generated/`

`chmod -R 777 var/`

`chown -R www-data:www-data generated/`

`chown -R www-data:www-data var`

`chown -R www-data:www-data pub/static/`